# Getting Dynamic Content oF MVC page in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I want the html content of entire page in C#.

Please refer below code

```
// WebClient object
WebClient client = new WebClient();

// Retrieve resource as a stream
Stream data = client.OpenRead(new Uri("xxxx.html"));

// Retrieve the text
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
string htmlContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

**the above one gives the static content of html. in my html some dynamic content of an particluar element will be added in jquery.**

for ex: **xxxx.html**

```
..........

<div id="asc"></div>
........
```

am adding the content of asc dynamically in jquery like

```
$("#asc").html("dddd");
```

after that i want to get entire page html in C#. it still giving static content of html.

how can i get dynamic content of entire page in C#.

i need to get the html of entire page and make to export in PDF.

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: Please see the below link. it might helps you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546315/asp-net-reading-dynamically-generated-html-element-value-in-codebehind